# possible bashism: echo -e

Tags: bash, shell

I am using following shebang in my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

To check whether I haven't used any bash syntax, I checked my script with checkbashisms script and it says

```
possible bashism in my_script.sh line 3 (echo -e):
                              echo -e "hello world"
```

And I am running this script on embedded board with busybox shell.

How to resolve this?

Comment: You need to provide the relevant parts of the code. Do you need the `-e` flag or not? We cannot know that without seeing some code.

Comment: The `-e` option is for `echo` to parse escape code (used for example for VT100 escape codes or embedded newlines etc.). If your string doesn't have any escape code, then you don't need it.

Comment: Also, the `-e` option is not in [the POSIX standard for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). It's less of a "Bashism" and more of a GNUism" I would say, especially since in Linux it's not only a Bash built-in command, but also part of [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/echo-invocation.html#echo-invocation).

Comment: If you are on Linux (or, more generally, on a system where /usr/bin/echo supports -e), you can write `command echo -e ...`.  The `command` command, which is part of the POSIX standard, causes the `echo` from your PATH to be executed, instead of the builtin `echo`.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX allows `echo -e` as the default behavior. You may do

```
var="string with escape\nsequence"

printf "%s\n" "$var" # not interpreting backslashes 
printf "%b\n" "$var" # interpreting backslashes
```

This should pass the `checkbashisms` test

Answer (score 2):

```
help echo
```

> ```
> -e    enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
> ...
> ```

If your code doesn't need to interpret backslash escapes then you can safely remove the `-e` flag.

Sometimes, people tend to use `-e` just for interpreting `\n` as newline. If that's the case, know that you can have multiline strings just by quoting them and writing as it is. An example:

```
var="Hi,
I am
a multiline
string"
```

But if you do need to interpret backslash escapes, then using `printf` will be your best bet.

Though I would recommend using `printf` whether you need backslash interpretation or not.

With `printf`:

```
printf "%s\n" "$var" # no backslash interpretation
printf "$var"        # backslash interpretation occurs
```

Comment: `echo` is a shell builtin.  While the `man` pages might correctly describe it on a GNU system, they are probably for `/bin/echo` which (in theory) could be different.  On the version of UNIX I am running on, the shell built-in supports `-e` but `/bin/echo` does not, and the `man` pages do not have the line you show, however `help echo` does.  There can be similar issues with `printf`, being both a shell built-in and a program in (on my system) `/usr/bin`.